# PHP conditional working on Chrome, but not working on FF or Safari

Tags: php, cookies, cross-browser

I have a simple conditional if/else statement in PHP to display content depending on whether a cookie is set or not. The problem is, it only seems to work as expected on Chrome, and not Safari or FF.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['formFilled'])) {
     print('content unlocked');
} else {
     print('content locked');
}
```

I know the cookies are set because I can see them in the Storage tab in the devtools (Application tab in Chrome), and the "formFilled" cookie is being sent to the server as seen in the network tab. **But no matter whether the cookie 'formFilled' is set, or not, the content remains unlocked.** In other words, the first condition is always true in FireFox, but not Chrome.

[image]

PHP is a sever-side language, so why does this work in Chrome and not Safari or FF (where it always shows as 'unlocked')?

Comment: Maybe something blocks the cookie to be set. Try with a fresh profile and no plugins.

Comment: BTW, use echo (without brackets) instead of print. Print is a function while echo is a language construct and therefore faster.